# Is it bad practice to filter by ID within the repository pattern

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I am using ASP.NET **MVC4** with **Entity Framework 5**.

Essentially every controller action result **filters the db results by the logged in Users' Company ID**. I have just begun implementing a repository pattern to return the models rather than directly filtering the DbContext from the controller. (Passing the companyID into the repository to filter results of methods)

I have a funny feeling that it is bad practice to do this, but have been unable to find any information on the subject. I will insert a basic version of my current code below, I would appreciate any information about whether or not it is bad practice, and why so.

**IBookingSystemRepository.cs**

```
public interface IBookingSystemRepository : IDisposable
{
    IEnumerable<Appointment> GetAppointments();
    IEnumerable<Appointment> GetAppointments(bool includeDeleted);
    IEnumerable<Client> GetClients();
    IEnumerable<Client> GetClients(bool includeDeleted);
    void Save();
}
```

**BookingSystemRepository.cs**

```
public class BookingSystemRepository : IBookingSystemRepository
{
    private BookingSystemEntities db;
    int CompanyID;

    public BookingSystemRepository(BookingSystemEntities context, int companyID)
    {
        this.db = context;
        this.CompanyID = companyID;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Appointment> GetAppointments()
    { return GetAppointments(false); }

    public IEnumerable<Appointment> GetAppointments(bool includeDeleted)
    {
        return includeDeleted
            ? db.Appointments.Where(a => a.User.CompanyID == CompanyID)
            : db.Appointments.Where(a => a.User.CompanyID == CompanyID && a.Deleted.HasValue);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    { return GetClients(false); }

    public IEnumerable<Client> GetClients(bool includeDeleted)
    {
        return includeDeleted
            ? db.Clients.Where(c => c.CompanyID == CompanyID)
            : db.Clients.Where(c => c.CompanyID == CompanyID && c.Deleted.HasValue);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (db != null)
            db.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**TestController.cs**

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private BookingSystemEntities db = new BookingSystemEntities();

    public ActionResult AppointmentsList()
    {
        var user = db.Users.Single(u => u.Email == User.Identity.Name);
        IBookingSystemRepository rep = new BookingSystemRepository(db, user.CompanyID);
        return View(rep.GetAppointments());
    }
}
```

Thankyou in advance for your assistance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a multi-tenant application.  The filtering is needed to keep each company's data separate.  Your approach is a sound one; if possible, provide a context that is already filtered, rather than filtering in the downstream repository methods individually.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help and speedy response :) I didn't even think of filtering the context before passing it to the repository, I think your approach will make things even simpler for me!
Just to clarify though, do you mean for me to create a new DbContext class that filters all DbSets based on an ID passed to the constructor?

Comment: That would be an interesting idea.  It would be nice if you could pull it off.  No, I was thinking more of a repository or DBContextWrapper class that would feed your normal repository.  From a security standpoint, the best way to feed the DBContext would be to provide Views in your database engine that are already filtered.  But I don't know how much time you have. :)

Comment: So essentially make another repository, between this one and the DbContext, that filters everything to company level?
Your idea about filtering it using database views is probably the best option, but I don't have the time to do that currently.
Anyhow, many thanks for your assistance Robert. :)